# Installing beaker server

Tags: beaker-testing

I have been trying to install Beaker server on Fedora 26 following the instructions in https://beaker-project.org/docs/admin-guide/installation.html#installing-the-beaker-server.I've done setting up Beaker database and enabling beakerd scheduler, but I'm stuck when I come to the step of configuring the URL for beaker server on Apache (as provided in the link and the image).[the instruction i'm stuck on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyGed.png)

I'm not sure what is the URL of my Beaker server (where to find it in the config file?). Should I config that URL in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf or /etc/httpd/conf.d/beaker-server.conf? I gave a try on both but all I can manage is displaying the index.html file of the server, not the Beaker server UI as expected. I configured the server name to be the IP of the server since I want to test first before contacting the DNS provider.

Thank you for your help on the matter.

Answer (score 0):

The default `/etc/httpd/conf.d/beaker-server.conf` file configures the Beaker web application to be served under the path `/bkr/`. That's this line (and all the related settings):

```
WSGIScriptAlias /bkr/ /usr/share/bkr/beaker-server.wsgi/bkr/
```

So you should find Beaker accessible at http://$YOURSERVER/bkr/. That's what the documentation means when it says "the URL configured in Apache".

If you just visit http://$YOURSERVER/ you will indeed see the Apache welcome page because nothing else is configured to be served at the root.

Comment: I tried that URL and it shows Internal Server Error with the logs in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log beaker. Unfortunately the log is too long for this comment so i'll post it below.